# Music lens doesn't work

Tags: unity, 12.10, lenses

My brother did something and now the music lens doesn't work. Now there's no filter and no search results. Yesterday, everything worked.

How do I reinstall this lens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and execute the following command.

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-lens-music`

This should reinstall the music lens.